# CameraComponent how to set Macro focus

Tags: delphi

I try to make photo in a Macro mode but can't get true result.

I use CameraComponent but FMX.Media doesn't have a Macro mode.

FMX.Media.TFocusMode.AutoFocus - has problem with photographing from close range.

I use Delphi XE8 sp1 and Samsung Galaxy Note

Need help.